# CSS Positioning Mixup

Tags: css

I have a document with notes that should display when the user hovers over the [note] indicator without disrupting the rest of the text. Here is my CSS:

```css
.nb {
  color: blue
}
.nb sup {
  color: blue
}
.nb:hover sup {
  cursor: alias
}
.nb:hover span.ft {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -30px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.ft {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<span class='sentence'>This is a lovely sentence about nothing at all<span class='nb'><sup>[a]</sup><span class='ft'>or is there more to the story?</span></span>and I like to ramble on and on, and on.</span>
<span class='sentence'>This is another nice sentence, but this one has no notes--how boring.</span>
```

I would like for my drop-down text to not disrupt the rest of the line it's on (or the lines below it), but I have not been successful.

Comment: A working jsFiddle reproducing your issue would be helpful

Comment: OK, I did it: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=wOucuhhugN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.nb {
  color: blue
}
.nb sup {
  color: blue
}
.nb:hover sup {
  cursor: alias
}
.nb:hover span.ft {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.ft {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<span class='sentence'>This is a lovely sentence about nothing at all<span class='nb'><sup>[a]</sup><span class='ft'>or is there more to the story?</span></span>and I like to ramble on and on, and on.</span>
<span class='sentence'>This is another nice sentence, but this one has no notes--how boring.</span>
```

Comment: That sort-of solves it, but it covers up the flow of the sentence. I'm trying to get it to display below the current sentence.

Comment: Why don't you give it a top margin. Ex: `margin-top:20px;`

Comment: Bingo, that was the missing piece. Thanks to all who had the same solution, but for the margin-top:20px comment, chillvivek gets the points.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nb {
  color: blue
}
.nb sup {
  color: blue
}
.nb:hover sup {
  cursor: alias
}
.nb:hover span.ft {
  display : inline-block;
  position : absolute;
  color : black;
  border : solid 1px black;
  padding : 4px;
  background-color : white;
}
.ft {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<span class='sentence'>This is a lovely sentence about nothing at all<span class='nb'><sup>[a]</sup><span class='ft'>or is there more to the story?</span></span>and I like to ramble on and on, and on.</span>
<span class='sentence'>This is another nice sentence, but this one has no notes--how boring.</span>
```

Use `absolute` CSS positioning as it will let the box behave without the others elements constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nb {
  color: blue;  position: relative;
}
.nb sup {
  color: blue
}
.nb:hover sup {
  cursor: alias
}
.nb:hover span.ft {
  display: inline;
position:absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.ft {
  display: none; width:190px;
}
```

```html
<span class='sentence'>This is a lovely sentence about nothing at all<span class='nb'><sup>[a]</sup><span class='ft'>or is there more to the story?</span></span>and I like to ramble on and on, and on.</span>
<span class='sentence'>This is another nice sentence, but this one has no notes--how boring.</span>
```